# Import CA.pem file to Jmeter to push the message to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter

We are trying to push the message via Jmeter to kafka topics. We tried to push the message by using Java request with all the Kafka topic details but in order to successfully see the message in the topic , there needs a CA.Pem file to be imported to Jmeter to establish the connection.

Could anybody help in importing the .pem file in Jmeter  ?

Comment: Can't you just add some `ssl.keystore.location` property to the producer config?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't support certificates in PEM format, you need to convert it to Java [keystore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html) first using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) tool or [Keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html)

Once you have the keystore you should be able to make JMeter aware of it by specifying the relevant SSL properties in the [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator plugin](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box):

[image]

More information on the plugin installation and usage: [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)